# How to hide "Automatic reconciliation" button from Qweb in Odoo10?

Tags: odoo, qwebview, odoo-10, qweb, odoo-view

Go to Accounting => Accounting Dashboard => click on Reconcile button

[image]

We get below Qweb view.

[image]

In that Qweb view, How can we hide "Automatic reconciliation" button ?

I have tried following but didn't work:

```
<templates xml:space="preserve">

    <!-- 1st try -->
    <t t-name="automatic_reconciliation_1st" t-extend="reconciliation">
        <t t-jquery=".btn" t-operation="replace"></t>
    </t>

    <!-- 2nd try -->
    <t t-name="automatic_reconciliation_2nd" t-extend="reconciliation">
        <t t-jquery=".js_automatic_reconciliation" t-operation="replace"></t>
    </t>

    <!-- 3rd try -->
    <t t-name="automatic_reconciliation_3rd" t-extend="reconciliation">
        <t t-jquery=".oe_form_sheet oe_form_sheet_width o_form_sheet" t-operation="replace">
            <div class="oe_form_sheet oe_form_sheet_width o_form_sheet">
                <h1><t t-esc="title"/></h1>
                <div t-if="! hide_progress" class="progress progress-striped">
                    <div class="progress-text"><span class="valuenow">0</span> / <span class="valuemax"><t t-esc="total_lines"/></span></div>
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" t-att-aria-valuemax="total_lines" style="width: 0%;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oe_clear o_clear"></div>
                <div class="notification_area"></div>
                <div class="interface_options oe_form o_form"></div>
                <div class="reconciliation_lines_container"></div>
                <div class="show_more_container"><button class="show_more btn btn-default btn-sm">Show more... (<span class="num_items_remaining"></span> remaining)</button></div>
                <p class="o_protip text-muted" align="right">Tip: Hit CTRL-Enter to reconcile all the balanced items in the sheet.</p>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>

</templates>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .

```
<t t-name="account.reconciliation">
    <div class="o_form_view"><div class="oe_form_sheetbg o_form_sheet_bg"><div class="oe_form_sheet oe_form_sheet_width o_form_sheet">
        <h1><t t-esc="title"/></h1>
        <div t-if="! hide_progress" class="progress progress-striped">
            <div class="progress-text"><span class="valuenow">0</span> / <span class="valuemax"><t t-esc="total_lines"/></span></div>
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" t-att-aria-valuemax="total_lines" style="width: 0%;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="oe_clear clearer"></div>
        <div class="notification_area"></div>
        <div class="interface_options oe_form o_form"></div>
        <div class="reconciliation_lines_container"></div>
        <div class="show_more_container"><button class="show_more btn btn-default btn-sm">Show more... (<span class="num_items_remaining"></span> remaining)</button></div>
        <p class="o_protip text-muted" align="right">Tip: Hit CTRL-Enter to reconcile all the balanced items in the sheet.</p>
    </div></div></div>
</t>
```

Alternative solution:

```
.js_automatic_reconciliation { display:none; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried with your answer but still output is same. Do you have any alternative solution for these ?

Comment: .js_automatic_reconciliation {
      display:none;
}